# Enabling remote connection to Windows 7 local IIS asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7, remote-connection

I can access the website from localhost:12345 and private IP (192.168.1.70:12345) but I cannot access it from my public IP. I used port 12345 because I think Telus blocks port 80.

1. Windows firewall shouldn't be an issue because I can access it from computers in LAN.
2. I port forwarded TCP port 12345 on my Telus router.

What else can I do if (public IP:12345) still times out?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was working as expected. If I go to http://www.canyouseeme.org/ I can see that port 12345 is open.

The reason it was still timing out for me is likely due to Telus not allowing computers on its LAN to access the public IP from within the LAN.